# Errors when trying to set command-line values via snakemake profile file

Tags: python, snakemake

I'm trying to get the `--profile` argument to snakemake (version 5.20.0 running on Ubuntu 20.04) to work. I have a profile directory set up with a `config.yaml` file in it. If I put this into `config.yaml`:

```yaml
verbose: 1
```

and run `snakemake --profile xxx target`, all goes well. However, if the config file contains

```yaml
set-threads: "trim=7 diamond_dna=5"
```

snakemake complains:

```
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce --set-threads=trim=7 diamond_dna=5 (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

So it looks like an `=` is being put into the `--set-threads` argument, which snakemake then interprets as a target I want to make.  (I get the same thing if I use `set-threads: "'trim=7 diamond_dna=5'"` in case anyone is wondering - even though I don't think Python's `argparse` would handle that correctly, if it got that far).

If I put this into the config file:

```yaml
verbose: 1
set-threads: "trim=7 diamond_dna=5"
```

I sometimes get

```
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce --verbose (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

but other times get

```
MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce --set-threads=trim=7 diamond_dna=5 (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

Yes, the error changes for the exact same input config file. I guess snakemake is considering both `--verbose` and `--set-threads=trim=7 diamond_dna=5` to be targets in both cases and (in some way) randomizing which one it decides to try to make first.

In any case, I am clearly doing something wrong or not understanding how `--profile` is supposed to work. Any help would be much appreciated!  I have seen https://github.com/snakemake-profiles/doc but it doesn't shed any light on this.

Comment: Can you try instead: `verbose: True` and `set-threads: "'trim=7 diamond_dna=5'"`? The latter one has single quotes surrounding them.

Comment: Hi @ManavalanGajapathy, thanks. I had already tried the single quotes (as above). Using `verbose: True` doesn't change anything. Thanks for the suggestion, though!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with the following in the `config.yaml` file:

```yaml
verbose: True
set-threads: ["trim=7", "diamond_dna=5"]
```

Note that due to the way Python's `argparse` deals with arguments that are `nargs='*'` you might need to play around with the order you put things like `--set-threads` and `--config` on the `snakemake` command line.

Also, *do not use `--` to signal the end of options* before giving the target(s) to be made: doing so will cause `trim=7` etc (as in my example) to be interpreted as snakemake targets, due to `argparse` appending them to the command line and snakemake using `nargs='*'` for its `target` command line option.