# Snakemake interprets profile config file as a target and returns error

Tags: snakemake

I am running a Snakemake pipeline on a Slurm managed cluster. I run the pipeline with this command:

```
snakemake  -n --use-conda --conda-prefix ./envs/ --cores 4 --configfile example/config/config-test.yaml --profile ./example/slurm/
```

Where `example/slurm` is a folder containing a `config.yaml` file that looks like this:

```
cluster: 
  mkdir -p logs/{rule} &&
  sbatch
    --partition={resources.partition}
    --qos={resources.qos}
    --cpus-per-task={threads}
    --mem={resources.mem_mb}
    --job-name=smk-{rule}-{wildcards}
    --output=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-%j.out
    --account=gfrances
default-resources:
  - partition=cpu
  - mem_mb=16000
restart-times: 3
max-jobs-per-second: 10
max-status-checks-per-second: 1
local-cores: 1
latency-wait: 60
jobs: 500
keep-going: True
rerun-incomplete: True
printshellcmds: True
scheduler: greedy
use-conda: True
```

However, when launching the workflow it immediately exit with this error:

```
No rule to produce --cluster=mkdir -p logs/{rule} && sbatch --partition={resources.partition} --qos={resources.qos} --cpus-per-task={threads} --mem={resources.mem_mb} --job-name=smk-{rule}-{wildcards} --output=logs/{rule}/{rule}-{wildcards}-%j.out --account=gfrances (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).
```

It seems like my config is parsed as a target of a rule - and I don't understand why. I can run successfully the same workflow locally without Slurm. Sankemake version is 8.2.1.

Any advice is appreciated, I am not very familiar with Snakemake but I have been able to run multiple pipelines (not in slurm systems).

I expect the pipline to run without errors as in local. I tried to use multiple config templates found on github, all leading to the same error so far. In other cases, the error becomes different and reports that no `--cluster` argument for Snakemake is available, although it clearly is.

A similar issue is reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198867/errors-when-trying-to-set-command-line-values-via-snakemake-profile-file), but the solution and reasoning behind it are not clear at all to me.

Comment: I believe that in Snakemake>8 you should be using the SLURM executor plugin. Snakemake made some big (likely breaking) changes in 8.0, and there is some confusion about this. Here is the relevant documentation: https://snakemake.github.io/snakemake-plugin-catalog/plugins/executor/slurm.html